# Add Time to SQL DateTime PHP

Tags: php, sql, datetime, timestamp, addition

I have a program that when someone clicks a button I want to add an hour onto every dateTime in my SQL database. For instance if the original dateTime was 2013-02-18 01:00:40.330, when the button is clicked it will become 2013-02-18 02:00:40.330. Is there any way to do this maybe with an UPDATE clause?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use addtime() for that:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime
```

Or in Code:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(YOURTIMEFIELD, '1:0:0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your update query.

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming exampletable is your table and time111 is the column you have to update 
try this :-

```
UPDATE exampletable SET time111 = DATEADD(hour, 1, time111)
```